# date('l') doesn't work as expected when adding 2 days to a current date time

Tags: php

So this is my code:

```
$date = new \DateTime('now +2 days');   
echo date("l")."<br>";
echo date("l", $date->format('Y-m-d'))."<br>";
echo date_format($date, "Y-m-d");
```

and this is the output:

```
Wednesday
Thursday
2023-10-13
```

/////////////

Today is 11.10.2023
For todays date the date('l') gives a correct answer, but for the $date that i created it says thursday even though it should say friday?
if i echo the date it gives the correct date.
Am I doing anything wrong???

I tried to add 2 days to a todays date and output the day of the week but it doesn't work as expected

Comment: `date("l", $date->format('Y-m-d'))` doesn't do what you think it does. The second parameter needs to be a **timestamp**, not a date in a string format. It's showing Thursday because January 1st 1970 (the Unix epoch) was a Thursday - your string is being interpreted as zero. If you want to format your datetime object as a weekday, use the object's own [`format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method

Comment: Don't mix `date()` with `DateTime`. In fact, don't use any of the old date&time function (those from [this list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) that do not work with a `DateTime` or related class). Use the `DateTime` class and the other [related classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). The old `date()` and `time()` and the other date&time functions are limited, some of them cannot work with timezones and for those that can, the timezone is a global setting. The classes have full support for timezones and using them is much easier than using the old functions.

Comment: Simply : `$date->format('l');`. And also you should get a fatal error in your code : `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: date(): Argument #2 ($timestamp) must be of type ?int, string given`

Comment: It should be `$date->format("l")` rather than `date("l", $date->format('Y-m-d'))`. But, as already said, mixing objects, Unix times and strings makes date handling more complex that it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix `date()` with `DateTime`. In fact, don't use any of the old date&time function (those from [this list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) that do not work with a `DateTime` or related class). Use the `DateTimeImmutable` class and the other [related classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). The old `date()` and `time()` and the other date&time functions are limited, some of them cannot work with timezones and for those that can, the timezone is a global setting. The classes have full support for timezones and using them is much easier than using the old functions.

Back to your code.

```php
$now = new \DateTimeImmutable('now');
$date = $now->add(new DateInterval('P2D'));

echo('Now: '.$now->format('Y-m-d (l)')."\n");
echo('The day after tomorrow: '.$date->format('Y-m-d (l)')."\n");
```

Check it online: https://3v4l.org/amqSe

Read about [class `DateTimeImmutable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php), [method `DateTimeImmutable::add()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.add.php) and [class `DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) in the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/).

---

P.S. There is nothing wrong with `new \DateTime('now +2 days')`. It is just a personal preference to use `DateInterval` because it expresses an interval of time in a non-ambiguous form.
The [constructor of class `DateTime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) accepts a date [expressed in various ways](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) in the English language but, sometimes, [a little detail may produce an unexpected outcome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28218533/4265352).

Comment: Constructs like `'now +2 days'` are the regular expressions of date handling. Powerful, useful and deadly.